# Session Bean Data is lost after page reload or page change

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'm working on a JSF Project using a Wildfly 8 Server and jsf 2.2.

I've a web part with xhtml and beans + ejb part with models etc and a mysql database.

Part of Model (EJB part): Foo.java

```
String name = "";

Object Foo2 = new Foo2();
```

Part of Model (EJB part): Foo2.java

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

String name = "";
```

Now I've input like this: input.xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:event listener="#{ InputBean.init() }" type="preRenderView" />
</f:metadata>

<h:inputText 
    value="#{ InputBean.actualFoo.name }">
</h:inputText>

<h:selectOneMenu                                    
     value="#{InputBean.currentSelectedFoo2_ID}">
         <f:selectItems value="#{InputBean.lhm_AllFoo2}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

and a bean: InputBean.java

```
@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "InputBean")
public class InputBean implements Serializable

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Long currentSelectedFoo2_ID;

private LinkedHashMap<String, Object> lhm_AllFoo2;

private Foo actualFoo;

public InputBean() {
    lhm_AllPermissions = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    actualFoo = new Foo();
}

public void init()

    // Method of interface in EJB part which gives me all Foo2 to a list 
    List<Foo2> list_AllFoo2 = foo2Interface.getAllFoo2;

        if ((list_AllFoo2 != null) && (list_AllFoo2.size() > 0)) {
            for (Foo2 foo2 : list_AllBFoo2) {
                lhm_AllFoo2.put(foo2.getName(), foo2.getId());
            }
        }
```

When I input data in the inputField and select data the selectonemenu and then reload the page (f5) or change to another page (of the same project) and go back the data in the input field is still avaiable but the selectonemenu is reseted to the default value.

I tried to debug the problem, but the data is already lost when the init is accessed, no setter of the bean is called before. The constructer isn't called too, so everything seems to be correct. The bean data which isn't linked to an input isn't lost too.

Is this a normal JSF problem and is there a way to solve that?

Comment: but post code in an [mcve] format... And debug your application. Set breakpoints check what happens... I'm almost 100% sure you will find the cause then

Comment: I wanted to give you as less unuseful code as possible, thought such minimalistic code is better to find the problem. I also thought it's a jsf typical problem becaue I've the problem in every part of the project where input isn't written in a model directly. I've debugged through the whole bean and both models, the code is already lost when they're accessed.  I've added the SelectedFoo2_ID, will take some time to give you more data because it's sensible. Thanks for the response so far :)

Comment: Are you obtaining EJB objects by `new` instead of injecting within constructor instead of `@PostConstruct`?

Comment: Found the problem. I didn't add ajax to each input field, so they don't save the data to the bean directly.